# ffmpeg adding subtitles with options

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video, subtitles

Hi I'm having trouble adding options to subtitles: I can only add 1 attribute.

`ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -vf 'subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style=Fontname=Z003,PrimaryColour=&HCCFF0000' -y "out.mp4"`
Not working.

in https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1 is:

"ASS style format KEY=VALUE couples separated by ","."

but the sample script does not work. The script works only with 1 attribute, example:

`ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -vf 'subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style=Fontname=Z003' -y "out.mp4"`
Works.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Originally, I wanted to add white subtitles on a black background to the video.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
"subtitles=\'<srt_path>\':force_style='FontName=Z003,PrimaryColour=&HCCFF0000&'"
```

Note the double quote around the whole subtitles part, and the trailing ampersand of the PrimaryColour.